# Getting user input from script used as stdin for SSH session

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh, stdin

I have a shell script which runs commands and asks for user input.  The script is located on my computer.  I'm using the script as stdin for an ssh session to execute commands remotely.  The problem I'm having is the read command doesn't seem to wait for user input.  Is there anyway to prompt for user input in an SSH session using a script as stdin?

local shell:

```
ssh root@10.0.0.1 < example.sh
```

example.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
#example.sh

echo "Enter Name"
read user_name

#script doesn't wait for user input
```